# read value in taxonomy field

Tags: taxonomy, taxonomyfieldvalue

I want to read value from taxonomy field

when I debug I get the below values

```
item["Department"]
Count = 4
    [0]: {[_ObjectType_, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue]}
    [1]: {[Label, Some Department]}
    [2]: {[TermGuid, 345667-345-44230a-6574-453543]}
    [3]: {[WssId, 44]}
```

Now, I want to get that "Some Department" value from it. I tried accessing the label item["Department"][1] but it didnt work

I am not able to use

```
new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<string, object>(item["Department"]).Items[1].Value;
```

as it says

> Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level Package

How should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://c4968397007/");

// SharePoint web
Web web = clientContext.Web;

// Get the list using Title
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Custom");

// Get the list item by id
ListItem item = list.GetItemById(2);
clientContext.Load(item);

// Execute the query to the server
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


//get single taxonomy field value
TaxonomyFieldValue termValue = item["Department"] as TaxonomyFieldValue;

Console.WriteLine(termValue.Label);
```

Comment: its of type {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue}

Comment: yes check this. Have updated code.
 `//get single taxonomy field value
TaxonomyFieldValue termValue = item["Department"] as TaxonomyFieldValue;

Console.WriteLine(termValue.Label);`

Comment: taxFieldValueColl is coming as null

Comment: check now , have removed the taxfieldvaluecoll

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code

```
                        try
                        {
                            newItem["Department"] = ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)(item["PokagonDepartment"])).Label;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                          // some things to do on exception
                        }
```